# No ads error from adcontrol

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm checking out ads in a Windows Phone app for the first time.
When I tried with the test settings, the test app showed up.

When I replace the info by the applicationID and AdUnitId from PubCenter, 
nothing at all appeared (when debugging on a device).

I suscribed to the erroroccured event:

```
  private void AdControlInBorder_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message.ToString());
    }
```

And I get: "No ad available". This is about a second after the app started up.
Extra info: I'm in Belgium, checked it with the phone plugged to pc, unplugged,
I'm on wifi and I have internet available.

Comment: IIRC the fill rate for MS ads is quite low, it may be as simple as this.  Also, I seem to remember there being some issue with displaying actual ads in debug mode.

Comment: Are there any real alternatives for the PubCenter ads?

Comment: Have a look at using AdDuplex as a fall back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdDUplex is just for promote your app not for gain money :) In your case, you can't have ads in debug mode. Send your app in beta test and look if ads is available. Pub center have the best fill rate in wp8  platform. But you need to choice your app usage. If you app is a type like rss flow or news you need ads because you will have a lot of users connected for a long time and frequently. If you app is a productivity app, you will add in app purchase or send your app like a paid app or donation. Don't forget if you add ads, the possibility to remove.

Comment: Weird thing is: I checked "release" in Visual Studio instead of "debug" and deployed to a device. Most of the times I immediatly got the error "No ads available", one time however, I got an ad. I am now pending certification for the store. After that, I'll ask if somebody would be nice enough to check if there are ads appearing on the actual app :)

Comment: Pubcenter got a complexe gestion. More your app is downloaded and used, more you will have ads. Remember to match the category of the dev center and center pub.

Comment: I got my app submitted today, would you check if any ads appear and let me know where in the world you are?
http://www.windowsphone.com/nl-be/store/app/weird-funny-facts/6353f4b4-cc80-47be-bd79-bc5d834d0d8f

Comment: it's ok from france :)

Comment: Thank you very much MatDev8! If you ever need me to check something for you, just let me know!! :)